# nested json sql

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, json.net, azure-data-factory

I have a json column in a sql table called "report_json ". The strucute of json is as below

```
{
    "drugs": {
        "Codeine": {
            "bin": "Y",
            "name": "Codeine",
            "icons": [
                93,
                100,
                103
            ],
            "drug_id": 36,
            "pathway": {
                "code": "prodrug",
                "text": "is **inactive**, its metabolites are active."
            },
            "targets": [
                "OPRM1"
            ],
            "rxnorm_id": "2670",
            "priclasses": [
                "Analgesic/Anesthesiology"
            ],
            "references": [
                1,
                2,
                9,
                17,
                29,
                30,
                159,
                171
            ],
            "subclasses": [
                "Analgesic agent",
                "Antitussive agent",
                "Opioid agonist",
                "Phenanthrene "
            ],
            "metabolizers": [
                "CYP2D6"
            ],
            "phenotype_ids": {
                "OPRM1": "78",
                "metabolic": "6"
            },
            "relevant_genes": [
                "CYP2D6",
                "OPRM1"
            ],
            "dosing_guidelines": [
                {
                    "text": "Normal to reduced morphine formation. Use label recommended age- or weight-specific dosing. If no response, may need to consider alternative analgesics such as morphine or a non-opioid.",
                    "source": "Genotype predicted",
                    "guidelines_id": 103
                }
            ],
            "drug_report_notes": [
                {
                    "text": "Predicted codeine metabolism is reduced.",
                    "icons_id": 58,
                    "sort_key": 58,
```

my question is how can i get the bin and name data for all the values as the json contains an array for name.

for exampel my resulted output i need is

bin name

r.   Codeine

y.   Digoxin

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you posted is incomplete but presumably you need something like

```
SELECT bin = JSON_VALUE(d.value, '$.bin'),
      name = JSON_VALUE(d.value, '$.name')
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$.drugs') d
```

(On the assumption that the relevant parts of the JSON would be like the below)

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{
  "drugs": {
    "Codeine": {
      "bin": "r",
      "name": "Codeine",
      "icons": [
        93,
        100,
        103
      ]
    },
    "Digoxin": {
      "bin": "y",
      "name": "Digoxin",
      "icons": []
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: martin json format is in sql column , in this scenario how should i retirve this details

Comment: `SELECT bin = JSON_VALUE(d.value, '$.bin'),  name = JSON_VALUE(d.value, '$.name')
FROM YourTable CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(YourCol, '$.drugs') d`